# Conditionally mixing ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, mysql-5.7

I have a MySQL table where I want part of it sorted differently. For instance, I want the following result set:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 | #ascending
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  8 | #descending
|  7 |
|  6 |
|  5 |
+----+
```

I essentially want to do something like:

```sql
ORDER BY
  WHEN id <= 4 THEN
    id ASC
  ELSE
    id DESC
  END;
```

which is of course nonsense. Is there a sensical equivalent? I’ve tried using `UNION`, but subquery order is ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a two stage ordering process; the first part orders by whether `id` is less than or equal to 4, and the second orders by either `id` (for `id <= 4`) or `-id` (for `id > 4`) so that values greater than 4 sort descending:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
ORDER BY id <= 4 DESC,
         CASE WHEN id <= 4 THEN id ELSE -id END
```

Output:

```
id
1
2
3
4
8
7
6
5
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/702f88/2)

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Does the negation also work for timestamp/datetime values? Or is there a similar trick?

Comment: @Frungi no, there's no real concept of a negative date; you'd need to use something like this instead: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ec16f/1

Comment: That seems like it would be perfect, escept… http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a5f9b/1

Comment: I'm confused, are you trying to order by `id` or the `date` value? If just `id`, just use my original query...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It actually doesn’t seem like the conditional `DATEDIFF` works properly here at all. I know what *should* be happening in this `ELSE` clause, but I have no idea what’s producing these results. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b909c8/1

Comment: @Frungi I think it must have been because I was trying to order by differently typed values, using `DATEDIFF` in both parts of the `CASE` works: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b909c8/5

Comment: Perfect, thanks! And thanks for putting up with the extra bonus question!

Comment: @Frungi no problem at all - I'm glad it's working now. Sorry about the missteps along the way.

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted this answer but deleted it; I’m reposting because it’s still a valid answer.

Rather than working the order change into an `ELSE` clause, you can limit one rule to a subset and the next will apply to the rest:

```
ORDER BY id <= 4 DESC,
         CASE WHEN id <= 4 THEN id END ASC,
         id DESC;
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/702f88/5)